NextJS/Tailwind - Separate globals.css handling per directory?
I'm building a project using NextJS 14.2 and TailwindCSS. I'm using the App Router in Next. I need to support multiple domains from this app which will have unique routes/styling/components.
I have my directory structure set up as such -
├── app
│   ├── api
│   ├── domainA
│   |   ├── routes...
│   |   ├── globals.css (specific to domainA)
│   ├── domainB
|   |   ├── routes...
|   |   ├── globals.css (specific to domainB)
│   ├── domainC
│   |   ├── routes...
│   |   ├── globals.css (specific to domainC)
│   ├── global.css (mostly empty)
│   ├── layout.tsx (mostly empty)

When I do npm run build and npm run start, the application bundles all of the CSS together across all domains into a few different files like [longhash].css and serves it with every request. This is not good.
When I do npm run dev, it doesn't seem to cross-bundle my different domain CSS, but I do see all of the CSS gets put into files which get served on the requests.
How do I get this to build in a manner where it's not cross-contaminating CSS across domains/directories?

I found a solution using Tailwind directives. I created two Tailwind configuration files and imported them into global.css for each directory, each tailored to the specific content of that directory. For instance, in my admin directory configuration:
image showing the tw-config
image showing global.css
edit: very bad english fix
